# CSS modules and 3rd party libraries

Tags: reactjs, webpack, antd, css-modules

I looked for similar questions but nada. I have a case like this:

We are developing a react webpack project which is using antd version 4 and also css modules

```
.header .ant-menu {

}
```

this gives me:
`.header-[hash] .ant-menu-[hash]` which I don't want hash on ant classes or I want ant components to get hashed class names.

Note:
I will add webpack config as soon as possible since I am unable to reach my pc. Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

please note that antd has its own library for working with react. With it you don't use classes but premade react components. See [Antd design of react](https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce) for a quickstart. Hope it's an option in your project to use the library.

Comment: We are already using them but we don’t want certain things like hovering menu changes text color. We are having problem overwriting them in css modules. For now we simply use global keyword but it annoys me a bit looking for any other way